# I want to delete previously added class

Tags: jquery

I want to delete and add class in a same tag.

suppose I have a tag name:

```
<button class="a">change class</button>
```

now when i click this button by taking class selector.

```
$('.a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('c').removeClass('a');
 });
```

when class added. now I want remove class 'c' and add class 'a'.

```
$('body').on('click','.c', function(){
    $(this).addClass('a').removeClass('c');
 });
```

I tried this. but not working.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code hooking up a click handler to the `.a` elements hooks it up *directly* to the element. Later, when the delegated `.c` event happens, **both** handlers get run. You can see that if you put breakpoints in the handlers. Here, since you can't do breakpoints in Stack Snippets, I've added logging:

```js
$('.a').on('click', function(){
    console.log("Direct .a handler ran");
    $(this).addClass('c').removeClass('a');
});

$('body').on('click','.c', function(){
    console.log("Delegated .c handler ran");
    $(this).addClass('a').removeClass('c');
});
```

```css
.a {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.c {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button class="a">change class</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Instead, use a delegated handler for both `.a` and `.c`:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.a', function(){
    $(this).addClass('c').removeClass('a');
});

$(document.body).on('click', '.c', function(){
    $(this).addClass('a').removeClass('c');
});
```

You can see that if you put breakpoints in the handlers. Here, since you can't do breakpoints in Stack Snippets, I've added logging:

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.a', function(){
    $(this).addClass('c').removeClass('a');
});

$(document.body).on('click', '.c', function(){
    $(this).addClass('a').removeClass('c');
});
```

```css
.a {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.c {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button class="a">change class</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But note that if all you're doing is toggling classes on the elements that exist as of when your event hookup code runs, you could just use `toggleClass("a c")`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to toggle between classes.

use `toggleClass`.

```js
$('.a').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('c a')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="a">change class</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove last added class it to

add a class by make a string of class

and

remove a class from last of the string and updated string to element again.

---

Another way to is that
add your last added class as a "last-class" attribute in an element

and then after when need to remove class, take a value of "last-class" attribute value and use removeClass() for remove class from the element.